# React useState hooks initial value is null, after few seconds when got value then not updating where is use the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm collecting the client id from API, so I use hooks for set the client id, and useState hooks is working fine when get response. As the initial value is null so the clientId got null initially, but when hooks update even then clientId not get the value. Asked me if you need more explanation.

```
  const clientIdFromStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pageSettingData"));

  const [clientId, setClientId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const clientIds = () => {
      let returnId = "";
      if (clientIdFromStore) {
        returnId = clientIdFromStore.getData.google_clientID;
      }
      return returnId;
    };
    const id = clientIds();
    setClientId(id);
  }, [clientId, clientIdFromStore]);

  console.log("clientID", clientId);

  return (
    <GoogleLogin
      clientId={clientId}
      buttonText={t("login.loginGoogle")}
      onSuccess={responseGoogle}
      onFailure={responseGoogle}
      className="google-login goo__gle"
      cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just set the initial state of the clientId directly.
*Not tested

```
  const clientIdFromStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pageSettingData") ?? {});
  const [clientId, setClientId] = useState(clientIdFromStore?.getData?.google_clientID);
```

Comment: It's not working when I'm cleaning the local storage. Because I'm also getting clientIdFromStore is null initially, and when it gets the data then it's doesn't update.

Comment: You can't 'listen' to localStorage. It is only a function that returns the current value in storage at the time the function is called. So you will either need to store data in state mechanism that can trigger an update to that component. (A parent state where the API is called and pass props down, Redux, contextApi, etc) or poll for changes to local storage to see if something has changed.